# Sloshing water coming to rest?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, flow, dissipation

Something I've noticed is that when I jostle a glass of water, the water inside will start sloshing back and forth. Gradually, the water comes to rest. However, if I move the glass (i.e., translate it) in any direction, the water comes to rest much faster. Why?

Comment: Have you also compared it to moving (translating) the glass via jostling it hard enough?

Comment: How does the water know it is translating at constant speed?

Comment: When translating the water, are you suddenly accelerating to a constant speed of moving the glass, and then suddenly decelerating, noticing the settling occurring during the constant speed phase, or are translating the glass at a constant acceleration? More or less, same thing happens in a car, sudden stops and the car rocks back and fourth on the suspension, full acceleration doesn't see the car rocking.

Answer (score 4):

When picking up the glass, a soft human grip may interact with the movement of the glass caused by reaction against the moving water.  This will damp the movement of the water by absobing some of the energy.